# css do not apply if ancestor match

Tags: css

I would like to apply the css rule to the "specialMenu" if the ancestor does not contain "fixed-already". How can I do it?

```css
:not(.fixed-already) .specialMenu a
{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 14px 10px 14px !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: rgb(17, 46, 42);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-already">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="specialMenu">
      <a href="cesar">cesar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="specialMenu">
      <a href="cesar">cesar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what your current attempt reads in natural language (CSS selectors are read from right to left):

```
:not(.fixed-already) .specialMenu a
```

1. Target any `a` elements
2. that are descendants of any element(s) with CSS class `specialMenu`
3. which have to be descendants of any element(s) that do not have CSS class `.fixed-already`.

Now let's check that with your current HTML structure:

```html
<body><!-- matches 3. !! -->
<div class="fixed-already">
  <div class="menu"><!-- matches 3. !! -->
    <div class="specialMenu"><!-- matches 2. -->
      <a href="cesar">cesar</a><!-- 1. matches this one -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

So as you can see, the descendant selector   (space) doesn't work well for you in this scenario.

Instead, with your current approach, you'll have to tie your selector closer to your actual DOM structure with the help of child combinator `>`:

```
:not(.fixed-already)>.menu>.specialMenu>a
```

Now this reads:

1. Target any `a` element
2. that is a child of any element with CSS class `specialMenu`
3. which is a child of any element with CSS class `menu`
4. which is a child of any element that does not have CSS class `fixed-already`.

```css
:not(.fixed-already)>.menu>.specialMenu>a
{
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 14px 10px 14px !important;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background-color: rgb(17, 46, 42);
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed-already">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="specialMenu">
      <a href="cesar">cesar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="specialMenu">
      <a href="cesar">cesar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your case, changing the structure will lead to the same problem you found in my answer. For Example not having the link wrapped by a specialMenu or  have a span around the link will break the css either. In any case it is neccessery to have a css that is specific enough for the given html. I think adding code to answers posted by others, so they dont work is not the right way to go, because that can be easly be done with your answer too

Comment: @JarlikStepsto The difference being that in your case the *surroundings* may wreck your style definitions. Also, as I have explained "Instead, with your current approach, you'll have to tie your selector closer to your actual DOM structure", tying the CSS directly to the inner structure of the elements involved is the only way to make use of `:not(.class-name)` within the given cirumstances. That is not saying OP took a good approach HTML-wise.